# Problem in performing LOOCV

Tags: r, cross-validation, glm

I am trying to run LOOCV on my regression model. I tried to run it in [r](/questions/tagged/r) and encountered the following warning message:

> ```
> Warning message in y - yhat:
> "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”
> ```

This is my model:

```
x=glm(x,data = full_data)
mse_loocv=cv.glm(full_data,x)
mse_loocv$delta
```

Variables used in glm are:

```
x->
target_deathrate ~ avganncount + avgdeathsperyear + incidencerate + 
    medincome + popest2015 + povertypercent + studypercap + medianage + 
    medianagemale + medianagefemale + percentmarried + pctnohs18_24 + 
    pcths18_24 + pctbachdeg18_24 + pcths25_over + pctbachdeg25_over + 
    pctunemployed16_over + pctprivatecoverage + pctempprivcoverage + 
    pctpubliccoverage + pctpubliccoveragealone + pctwhite + pctblack + 
    pctasian + pctotherrace + pctmarriedhouseholds + birthrate + 
    Midwest + Northeast + South
```